# Randomly repalce values in array with None

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose there's an array

```
arr = np.array((0,0,1,2,0,1,2,2,1,0))
```

What I'd like to do is to randomly replace `n` values with `None`. What I tried is

```
n = 5
arr[[random.randint(0, len(arr)-1) for i in range(n)]] = None
```

but what I get is

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Why do you want `None` in your array? One of the reasons numpy arrays are so efficient at operations is that the entire array contains the same type of data. Adding a `None` would change this

Comment: @pho you're right. I'll change my approach!

Comment: `None` is a python object, not a number (float or integer).  So it can only be placed in an array with object dtype.  If that doesn't make sense to you, then this use of `None` is the wrong thing to be doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll first have to convert your array into float type and then you can replace random indices with `np.nan` (as `None` won't be supported by numpy):

```
n =5
arr = arr.astype(float)
idx = np.random.choice(len(arr),n ,replace=False)
np.put(arr, idx, [np.nan]*n)
print(arr)
```

Output:

```
[nan nan  1. nan  0. nan  2.  2. nan  0.]
```

Answer (score -1):

You could create a 'mask' and then use list comprehension to return the value or None from the original array.

```py
import numpy as np
import random

arr = np.array((0,0,1,2,0,1,2,2,1,0))

mask = np.random.randint(2, size=len(arr))

new_arr = np.array([x if y == 1 else None for (x,y) in zip(arr, mask )])

print(new_arr)
```

```
[None None 1 None 0 1 None None 1 0]
```